# JavaScript で入力値が指定した日付と一致した場合にメッセージを非表示から表示させたい

Tags: javascript

下記のコードでinputの値に自分の誕生日を入力すると、非表示になっているメッセージが表示されるようにしたいです。
jqueryでは表示できたのですが、javascriptのみでコードを記入すると
「Identifier ‘myBd’ has already been declared 」とエラーが出ます。
変数を2重に宣言していないと思うのですが、初心者のため何が問題なのかわからずご質問させていただきました。
どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。
最初はコードを外部読み取りで記載していましたが、インラインのみに修正しております。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style ="width: 500px; margin: 300px auto 0 auto;" class="input-group mb-3">
        <h1 style =" text-align: center; color: red; font-size: 50px; width: 100%; font-weight: bold; color: #458fa0; display: none">誕生日おめでとう！</h1>  
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      </div>
      <input type="date" id="birthday" class="form-control" value="1990-01-01" placeholder="誕生日">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const myBd = new Date (1990,1,25);
        const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

        document.getElementById('birthday').onchange = function(){
            let date = document.getElementById('birthday').value;
            if(date == myBd){
                h1.style.display = '';
            };
        };
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

//追記//
コメントをいただきありがとうございます。
コメントの内容を試して、こちらに記載しております。対応方法が間違っていましたら教えてください。

１，コメントでありました、「myBd」を「myBirthday」に変更しても
同じ内容でエラーが出ました。
２，質問に書かれていないコードとのことでしたが、何度見返しても上記のコードが全てでございました。
３，参考URLありがとうございます。試しに、
date == myBd.toDateString()
と追記してみましたが、エラー内容は同じでした。

また、試しにjavascriptの1番上のコード２行を入れ替えてみました。

const myBd =
const h1 =　
↓
const h1 =
const myBd =

すると、どちらを一番上にしても、一番上のコードの変数名にエラーが出ました。
もしわかる方がいましたら教えていただけますでしょうか。

//追記//
コメント
４，はい、HTMLをファイルに保存してブラウザで表示しています。
５，一度インラインのみで書いてみました。インラインのみは初めて書きましたので、間違いがあればご指摘をお願いいたします。エラー内容は一緒でございました。

Comment: ざっと見て、変数の宣言が重複しているようには見えませんが、念のため myBd  を myBirthday に変えてみていただき、同じエラーが出るか確認いただけますか？

Comment: 質問に書かれてない javascript のコードのどこかに myBd の宣言があるのでは？

Comment: JavaScript は詳しくありませんが、日付 (Date オブジェクト) を `==` で比較しているのがまず間違いな気がします。参考: [今日と一致する日付かどうかを判定する方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/maryjass/items/593cdea2cb02eab1759f)

Comment: このHTMLをどうやって動作確認していますか。HTMLをファイルに保存してそのファイルをブラウザで開いていますか?

Comment: 「質問に書かれていないコードとのことでしたが、何度見返しても上記のコードが全てでございました」<= それはあり得ないので見落としているのでしょう。こういう話もあります=> https://qiita.com/TRyota/items/d5a7a39da551612dbfd9  外部ファイルにしないで、すべてインラインで書いてみてください。もし、それでも同じ問題が出るなら、そのコードを質問欄に書いてください。

Comment: 「一度インラインのみで書いてみました」<= それで同じ問題 Identifier ‘myBd’ has already been declared が出たのですか？　自分の環境でそのコードをコピペして試してみましたが、そういう問題は出ませんけど？　後で回答欄に結果の画像を貼っておきます。

Comment: エディタで編集しているファイルとブラウザで開いているファイルが別のものだったりしませんかね。現在質問文にあるコードで already been declared のエラーは出ません。

Comment: 私の回答に対するコメントは、質問欄ではなくて、私の回答の下のコメント欄に書いてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 一度インラインのみで書いてみました

それで同じ問題 Identifier ‘myBd’ has already been declared が出たのですか？

自分の環境 (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2022 17.9.5 + IIS 10 Express, Chrome 123.0.6312.86) でそのコードをコピペして試してみましたが、そういう問題は出ませんけど？

結果の画像を貼っておきます。

Visual Studio に質問者さんのコードをコピペして実行すると、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ブラウザ（この場合 Chrome）が立ち上がって上のページが表示されるので、ディベロッパーツールを開く。Console には Identifier ‘myBd’ has already been declared というようなエラーは出てません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Source タブでブレークポイントを設定し、テキストボックスの日付を変更すると期待通り change イベントにアタッチしたリスナーに制御が飛んで、JavaScript はちゃんと動いていることが確認できる。

ただし、if(date == myBd) と h1.style.display = ''; がダメなので期待した結果にはなりません。そこは Identifier ‘myBd’ has already been declared とは違う話なので別途。

Comment: コメントに書き直しました！初心者のため的外れのご質問なら申し訳ありません。javascriptの、scriptタグ内のコードのみをコンソールにコピペして確認してましたので、「Identifier ‘myBd’ has already been declared 」とエラーが出ておりました。そういった抜粋はせず、コンソールを開いてエラーが出なければ問題ないの解釈でよいのでしょうか？
また、
if(date == myBd) と h1.style.display = ''; がダメとのご指摘ありがとうございます。
if(date === myBd) と　h1.style.display = block; など試してみましたが動きませんでした。
理解が乏しいため、よろしければどのように修正をすればいいのか教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 「javascriptの、scriptタグ内のコードのみをコンソールにコピペして確認してましたので」<= 意味が分かりませんが、もし、問題が出た後で html ファイルの中身だけを質問のコードに変更して試しているのだとすると、ブラウザのキャッシュの html コード（すなわち変更する前のコード）がブラウザにロードされていて、変更する前だから同じ結果になっているとか？　「if(date == myBd) と h1.style.display = ''; がダメ」というのはこのスレッドの本題とは違うことですので、このスレッドの問題が解決したら、新たに別のスレッドを立てて質問してください。

Comment: ご丁寧にお答えいただきありがとうございます。そもそもタグ内のコードのみをコンソールに張り付けること自体が不要な行為だったようですね！今回のエラーが、javasprictが期待する結果にならない原因だと思っていましたが、コードが間違っていることが原因とはっきりして良かったです。ありがとうございました!